# Using G1GC algorithm in prod do we have any algorithm that it has to do major gc after threshold level

Tags: g1gc

We are using G1GC algoritm in PRODUCTION, using this algorithm in -XX+useg1gc in environment. My question is a few servers in PROD are getting high heap usage about 95%, so do we have any arguments or option or mechanism that major GC should happen after reaching threshold level?

Answer (score 0):

From the Oracle docs:

> -XX:G1ReservePercent=n : Sets the amount of heap that is reserved as a false ceiling to reduce the possibility of promotion failure. The default value is 10.